# How to track app pool recycle in a web application?

Tags: c#, iis-7

Is any event of global.asax is being fired, once app pool is reset/recycled? What happens to pending requests in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Things happen in this order:

1. A new copy of the application is spun up, and all *new* requests are routed to it.
2. The old copy finishes serving any requests that were in progress before the recycle started.
3. The old copy shuts down

You should get an Application_End event at some point during the recycle for the appdomain that is shutting down.

Comment: Behavior depends on settings disallowOverlappingRotation (which prevents starting new app until the old app is shut down). Also i experienced, that long-running requests which was started in old app and then interrupted by pool recycling in the middle of processinsg, that they are started again in new app.